# How to get the filename according to my requirement C# DirctoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos();

Tags: c#, .net, getfiles

.
net winform

Now I get all the fileName under the specified directory.
the result is "0001_00001523_028155.sql"

but my goal is only to get "00001523"

how can I do that?

```
private void loadscriptfolder()
    {
        string folderName = this.textBoxScriptLocation.Text.Trim();
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
        if (dir.Exists)
        {
            FileSystemInfo[] fs = dir.GetFileSystemInfos();
            foreach (FileSystemInfo fs2 in fs)
            {
                FileInfo file = fs2 as FileInfo;
                if (file != null)
                {
                    listBoxResult.Items.Add(file);
                }                    
            }                
        }
    }
```

Thank you everyone!!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `getfiles`. This question is only about basic string operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just really need to get that part of the file name, then you can just do a string manipulation on its file name.

```
                FileInfo file = fs2 as FileInfo;
                if (file != null)
                {
                    listBoxResult.Items.Add(file.Name.Split('_')[1]);
                }
```

Comment: the value of file.Name.Split('_')[1] is right, but I got "Index was outside the bounds of the array." after I run it.

Comment: it would be better if you post the stack trace. It could be that your files don't follow a naming convention (eg. [digit]_[digit]_[digit].[extension name]), say `"12345.sql"`.  Which in turn fails the `file.Name.Split('_')` because when you split that filename by `_`, the array size is just 1. So having `[1]` will fail because you are accessing the **second** element in that split filename.

Comment: I may know the reason.

Comment: glad i was able to help. Welcome to Stackoverflow! btw, when asking for questions, you can see [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    string str = @"0001_00001523_028155.sql";
    var result = str.Split('_')[1];
```

Comment: But I don't know how to transfer the FileInfo to Array...

Comment: To get the file name - `file.Name`. from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx